# Don't lose answer content on the mobile site if I hit "post" after phone loses connection

Tags: feature-request, answers, ajax

This happens to me quite a lot. At best, it's frustrating and forces me to lose time rewriting answers. At worst, I don't have time, so potentially helpful answers never get posted.

- I'm on the mobile site, happily drafting an answer.
- For whatever reason, while writing I lose my connection, but I don't notice because I'm focused on writing this answer.
- I hit "post", and my browser goes to a blank no connection error page.
- I reconnect, hit "back", get back to the post answer form, and get an empty content box. My work's been lost.

---

Suggested solution:

- Have the current "post answer" button as a fallback in a `<noscript>`
- If JS is enabled, have the post answer button do the following:

  - Switch to a "Working..." indicator
  - Try to submit the answer via AJAX, without (yet) leaving the page
  - On success, move to the success page
  - On failure, display an so appropriate "Can't connect" message *without* leaving the page, so the user's work isn't lost, re-enabling the "Post answer" button so they can try again after fixing their connection